# Associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new to Rails .. 
i am having a Table named users (id,name)
and another table which has the additional information of the user  called 
user_details(id,user_id,additional_info) where additional_info is a hash .

In the User Model i added a line

```
has_one :user_details
```

And in the User_Detail model i added a line

```
belongs_to :user
serialize :additional_details, Hash
```

Now in the Users Controller i am having an action

```
# set_user_empid to set the hash value empid in the additional_info column for the current_user
    def set_user_empid  
           @user1 = current_user
           @user_detail1=@user1.user_details
           @user_detail1.additional_details[:empid] = params[:value]
           @user_detail1.save
           render :text => CGI::escapeHTML(@user_detail1.additional_details[:empid].to_s)

    end
```

The above one `@user1.user_details` shows me the error as

> NameError (uninitialized constant User::UserDetails):

But the same thing if i change the has_one to has_many i am getting the actual result...

Please give suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix here is to change `has_one :user_details` to `has_one :user_detail`, but really what you want is to get rid of the UserDetail model entirely and just move the column into the `User` model, so the users table has these columns: `id`, `name`, `additional_info` and then move the call to `serialize` into the `User` model. No real reason to have a separate table just for metadata.

Comment: I just changed the :has_one :user_details to has_one :user_detail and in the Users controller i used like current_user.user_detail and it workz .. THank u

Answer (score 1):

I believe since you are using user_details, pluralized, it is not able to pick it up. Could you try using has_one :user_detail